# Custom Composite elements in Webform - Drupal8

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-webform

I want to create Composite element for Education:

It should be like
School:
Major:
Graduated: Yes/No .
Year of Graduation: (If Yes) . 
Upload Transcript:

Add More[Button] .

Webform provides Address, Telephone etc by default as Composite elements. How can we do that for Custom Fields?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

There is a [great example for how to create a composite element](https://github.com/solsoft/Drupal8WebformCompositeExample) posted by lpalgarvio.

You simply need to extend the class `WebformCompositeBase` to implement your own composite element.

The composite elements which ship with Webform module give you some additional examples.

jrockowitz the webform 5 (D8) module maintainer he is wanting to [add such an example into the webforms module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2893508), I am sure that ticket will be updated, he is amazingly active in improving the Webforms module.

Comment: The best place to look is now the module's example modules in webform/modules/webform_example_composite, it really explains everything.